# While(! eof()) infinite loop C++

Tags: c++

Im a cs major, and I am having trouble with a lab assignment. I'm hoping someone here can give me a hand! We are working with input/output files right now, and I have managed to create an infinite loop using while(!in_stream.eof()). We are writing in c++. Here is my code

```
while(!in_stream.eof())
{
    getline(in_stream,Name);
    in_stream >> salary;
    taxes = GetTax(salary);
    totalTax += taxes;
    totalSalary += salary;
    grossSalary += (salary - taxes);

    printSalary(out_stream, Name, salary, taxes, count);

    getline(in_stream,Name);
    in_stream >> salary >> moveOn;


    cout << "ok"  << endl;
}
```

I feel i'm hitting the loop because I'm missing the \n character at the end of a line, but that is why I'm using moveOn. I'm hoping the moveOn Char will catch it, but it doesn't seem to be working.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: that cout statement is there so I can discern whether or not the loop has ended.

Comment: How are your variables declared?

Comment: Possible reason for downvote (it wasnt me): searching SO for "eof" will find you the above question ;)

Comment: All variables are doubles except moveOn, name, and count. moveOn is a char, and Name is a string. Count is a int.